# CSV with autofit column from lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, csv

I am exporting  csv from lightning component.
But I need to ensure that column in autofit as per the column data when downloaded.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a few minutes to read [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/319758/edit) your question to bring it up to a reasonable standard - you need to demonstrate that you have researched the problem, provide detail of a specific issue that you are facing (such as errors etc.) possibly including code snippets etc. Without this you are unlikely to get much help from the community, who are not here to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an excel/etc. issue than Salesforce. CSV as a file format cannot automatically adjust column size, because the size of columns in excel etc. is not stored in the data. It stands for "Comma-Separated Values", which basically means that it's a text file with data separated by columns.

Column 1,Column 2,Column3

Cell A,Cell B, Cell C

Because there is no column size data stored in CSV format, most spreadsheet applications will use a default column size, which may be larger or smaller than needed. The only way to control this behavior is to use a more complex file format, like XLSX or ODS.